# How to programmatically register Nlog extensions/layout renderers (NLog.Web.AspNetCore)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

There is a guide [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2) that uses a configuration file to register NLog for ASP.Net Core. I have followed it, but I'd like to configure things programmatically. Mostly everything works, but I cannot get ASP.Net Core layout renderers to work. They do work if I register them myself like this:

```
LayoutRenderer.Register("aspnet-request-url", typeof(AspNetRequestUrlRenderer));
```

I see that in file configuration there is a section for that:

```xml
<!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
<extensions>
   <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do that programmatically for all renderers that are in that assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that as follows:

```cs
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.RegisterItemsFromAssembly(assembly);
```

So for NLog.Web.AspNetCore:

```cs
var assembly = typeof(AspNetRequestUrlRenderer).Assembly;
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.RegisterItemsFromAssembly(assembly);
```